# What happened to the tomoe in Sasuke's Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden

Sasuke's Rinnegan (pre-chapter 700) had six tomoe.

[image]

In *Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage* chapter 6, when Sasuke's Rinnegan is shown, it doesn't have the tomoe:

[image]

[image]

What happened to the tomoe in his Rinnegan? Is this an error or is there something else to it?

Comment: The likelihood in this case is that Sasuke still has his special Rinnegan. It is likely not active at this point; instead, he's using the more standard Rinnegan.

Comment: @Makoto your answer was technically right but lacked evidence. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: It's not like there *was* much evidence to go on until this week anyhow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest manga of [Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Gaiden:_The_Seventh_Hokage_and_the_Scarlet_Spring), show us that his eye was weakened and that's why he didn't have tomoe in his [Rinnegan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan) or why he couldn't activate his [Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Eternal_Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan).

It was weakened because he tried to open [dimensions](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kaguya%27s_Dimension) with his eyes which consumes a lot of chakra, as Obito had tried before he died in the battle with [Kaguya](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kaguya_%C5%8Ctsutsuki).

[image]